# remove leading zeroes from a string / varchar in spark scala

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

I have a variable (23 bytes varchar) that has values with leading zeroes (ex: `0000000036754678`). How to remove the leading zeroes from this variable.

Comment: string.toint is not working for 23 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#regexp_replace(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:String,replacement:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) built-in spark function as follow, provided that you already loaded your data in a dataframe called `dataframe` and that the column containing your values is called `value`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, regexp_replace}

dataframe.withColumn("value", regexp_replace(col("value"), "^0*", ""))
```

If you have the following `dataframe` as input:

```
+----------------+
|value           |
+----------------+
|0000000036754678|
+----------------+
```

you will get the following result:

```
+--------+
|value   |
+--------+
|36754678|
+--------+
```

Comment: The resulting df value type would not be int in this case. I suggest you remove the regexp_replace function, which is also kind of a heavy task, and just cast the value: `.withColumn("value", col("value") cast "Int")`